# How To Make Navigation Dropdown Menu Work Properly In My Html Css Code?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I Want To Make Navigation Dropdown Menu Work Properly Because As A Beginner Struggling A Lot In This Concept

I Tried Lot To Make It Work Properly Even Hard For Me To Understand This Concept. Please Give Solution To My Code And Tips Also Needed

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below if you just want to practice. but if there is any particular design you are struggling with. please paste your code here. will check once

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this website will help you to create navigation drop down menu
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

or if you are strugling with design please paste your code here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).